# How to get token id from NFT contract

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin

I have created an NFT with the help of openzeppelin wizard. I got the following response on mintable method.

```
token.safeMint('0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266', 'http://wplugins.localhost/contract.json')
{
  tx: '0xb493554e41ccb3f6af221bf563353114d452b0086f925c9ad1b91bcb6f163706',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0xb493554e41ccb3f6af221bf563353114d452b0086f925c9ad1b91bcb6f163706',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0xa2ccf6978b7b433bba7d57d981dea8a3d7efcaa341ffb4c30bb35540932ee17c',
    blockNumber: 95,
    from: '0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
    to: '0x49fd2be640db2910c2fab69bb8531ab6e76127ff',
    cumulativeGasUsed: 161855,
    gasUsed: 161855,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [ [Object] ],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000100000800000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000200000000000000000000000002000000000000000000020002000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000',
    type: '0x2',
    status: true,
    effectiveGasPrice: '0x9503070d',
    rawLogs: [ [Object] ]
  },
  logs: [
    {
      removed: false,
      logIndex: 0,
      transactionIndex: 0,
      transactionHash: '0xb493554e41ccb3f6af221bf563353114d452b0086f925c9ad1b91bcb6f163706',
      blockHash: '0xa2ccf6978b7b433bba7d57d981dea8a3d7efcaa341ffb4c30bb35540932ee17c',
      blockNumber: 95,
      address: '0x49fd2BE640DB2910c2fAb69bB8531Ab6E76127ff',
      id: 'log_ff516e78',
      event: 'Transfer',
      args: [Result]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure how to get the tokenId from this response. I am running it to truffle console. I have tried different solutions from this stackexchange but as you see that i haven't received the `topics[]` arg under the log. I am using Solidity 0.8.2 version.

Contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Token is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("My Test Token", "MTT") {}

    function safeMint(address _to, string memory _tokenURI) 
        public 
        onlyOwner 
    {
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(_to, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 _tokenId) 
        internal 
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) 
    {
        super._burn(_tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i have solved it and i hope it will help to other newbies too like me.
The `tokenId` exists in the **rawLogs** data.

```
tx.then(t => t.receipt.rawLogs)
[
  {
    removed: false,
    logIndex: 0,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    transactionHash: '0x494f65b3c78455501d5a8950f77c0b8031e7591cebedc9afa5496647a9b6ce2b',
    blockHash: '0xafec3731344cf08d04eb621fc3d1c44e3539530698af630ed34fbbb7839695a2',
    blockNumber: 96,
    address: '0x49fd2BE640DB2910c2fAb69bB8531Ab6E76127ff',
    data: '0x',
    topics: [
      '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
      '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0x000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
      '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
    ],
    id: 'log_d73f58e2'
  }
]
```

So get the tokenId i have used the web3 utility.

```
web3.utils.hexToNumber(t.receipt.rawLogs[0].topics[3])
```

**Note: I used the truffle console for all that.**